# What could be causing my QT program to compile and run successfully in debug mode but not in release mode using qmake?

Tags: qt, release, qmake

I made a QT soft under linux.
I also compil it for windows.
I really don't understand why it compil and run fine in debug mode :
https://github.com/surfzoid/QtVsPlayer/actions/runs/5120917271/jobs/9208007636

But, if i keep the default release mode, it replace for example "NET_DVR_GetLastError" by "__imp_NET_DVR_GetLastError" and generate error "undefined reference to" like we can see here :
https://github.com/surfzoid/QtVsPlayer/actions/runs/5120768793/jobs/9207674580

I have the same result with qtcreator under win, but under linux, release or debug work!

i would like same compil success under win and linux, with debug or release mode

Comment: You might want to analyze your build logs. It looks like you miss to link against `hcnetsdk` library in release mode.

Comment: Thank you @vahancho you are complety right, i become old :-D , i don't see check box or button to define your coment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the log of the release build you will notice that the linker complains about missing `imp_NET_DVR_*` symbols. Those are a part of the `hcnetsdk` library which your application doesn't link to; you do it only for debug builds.